# Controling Selenium test speed in hudson

Tags: testing, selenium, hudson

There is Selenium plugin (RC) in Hudson and the builds are taking to too long and keep failing if the server takes a while to respond. I do not think putting in waits in the test files would be a good Idea as the test code will be bloated with "Waits" and would increase the build time and the tests can still fail if there is a delay in response.

I was wondering if the speed at which selenium test cases are executed can be controlled in Hudson? just like you drag the slider to reduce and maximise speed in the browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will be possible to control the speed of test execution from hudson/jenkins. However, you can set speed of a test by the following Selenium method (in this case Selenium will wait 1 second after each command):

```
selenium.setSpeed("1000");
```